# notepad++ How can I disable the auto indent in npp?

Tags: notepad++

my problem in npp is that it adds an indention when I'm adding a backspace.
For example, I'm inserting a backspace as shown in the linked picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrkHD.png]

Npp adds automatic whitespace at the beginning...

[image: whitespaces where added automatically...]

As this is a fixed-length record, it will destroy the file.
How can I disable this behavior?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select the menu option Settings - Preferences - MISC
- Uncheck the option Auto-Indent
- Click on the Close button
- restart Notepad++

Comment: This option is not available on the current version of Notepad++ (v7.8.5). Any idea where they moved it?

Answer (score 6):

They moved this option so I had to hunt around to find it again after an update.

1. From the menu, select Settings > Preferences > Auto-Completion
2. Uncheck the option Auto-indent

You may need to restart Notepad++ for it to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

In version 8.3.1 (64 bit running in Ubuntu linux 20.04) I found Auto-indent
in Settings -> Preferences -> Auto-Completion, it the upper right corner.

Comment: Thanks John, this is also true on Windows, running version 8.5.4.